# Sort coordinates (x,y) of a parabola y=ax^2+bx+c x=x1,x2,x3, x4. according to y coordinates

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, computational-geometry

I have tried a cpp codeblock:

```
bool comp(const pair<int,int>&A, const pair<int,int>&B)
{
    if(A.second<=B.second)
    {
        if(A.first>=B.first)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, x[10], y[10];
    cin>>a;
    cin>>b;
    cin>>c;
    for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
    {
        cin>>x[i];
        y[i]=a*x[i]*x[i]+b*x[i]+c;
    }
    vector<pair<int,int> >V;
    for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
    {
        V.pb(mp(x[i],y[i]));
    }
    for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
    {
        sort(V.begin(),V.end(),&comp);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<V.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<V[i].first;

        cout<<" "<<V[i].second<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

STDIN: `a b c x1 x2 x3...` and `x` is in sorted order i.e. `x1 < x2 < x3`. The Code should generate a new list (`y = y1 y2 y3`) using the parabola equation for every `x` and sort the above list with a run-time complexity of <= O(log n).
STDOUT: `x3,y3 x1,y1 x2,y2 ...` (assuming computed `y3 < y1 < y2..` ).
Code should NOT compute the Y's.   Multiplication on this compute node is "too" costly. The solution should identify a way of still sorting the list without computing the "y" values.
My code computes the y values. Can anyone find a method of sorting without computing the y values. A python code implementation would also work for me.

Comment: You cannot avoid calculation of y's, because you have to output them, right?

Comment: Your `comp` function does not follow a `strict-weak-order`.  It will return `true` if the parameters are `(A, B)` and then `(B, A)` if `A == B` in both the first and second components.  If you were to run this Visual Studio, and `A == B` (both `first` and `second` components are equal), the debug runtime would assert and end the program.  What you want to do is compare either strictly less-than or strictly greater than.  Using `<=` or `>=` in a comparison function is almost always wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The farther an `x` value is from the parabola's apex `x0`, the higher is its `y` value when `a` is positive and the lower its `y` value when `a` is negative.

```
    |x1 - x0| > |x2 - x0| && a > 0   --> y1 > y2
    |x1 - x0| > |x2 - x0| && a < 0   --> y1 < y2
```

When `a` is zero, your parabola is really a line and the `x` values are already sorted in the correct order when `b` is positive or in the reverse order when `b` is negative.

So when `a` isn't zero, find the apex:

```
    x0 = - b / (2*a)
```

Now find the value in your sorted list of `x` values that is closest to `x`:

```
    i = index(x: min(|x - x0|))
```

Add point `i` to the list. Create two indices:

```
    l = i - 1
    r = i + 1
```

Now take the point at either index `l` or `r` that is closer to the apex, and add it to the list. Update the index until you have exhausted the list.

Revert the list when `a` is negative. (Or add the items from the end of the list.)

**Edit**: Here's an implementation in Python. It pops elements off sub-lists rather than using array indices, but the logic is the same:

```
import bisect

def parasort(a, b, c, x):
    """Return list sorted by y = a*x*x + b*x + c for sorted input x."""

    if not x:
        return x

    if a == 0:                          # degenerate case: line
        if b < 0: return x[::-1]
        return x[:]

    x0 = -0.5 * b / a                   # apex of parabola

    i = bisect.bisect_left(x, x0) + 1   # closest point via bin. search
    l = x[:i][::-1]                     # left array, reverted
    r = x[i:]                           # right array

    res = []

    while l and r:                      # merge l and r
        if x0 - l[0] > r[0] - x0:       # right item is smaller
            res += [r.pop(0)]
        else:                           # left item is smaller
            res += [l.pop(0)]

    res += l + r                        # append rest of arrays

    if a < 0: return res[::-1]        
    return res



a = 4
b = 0
c = 0
xx = parasort(a, b, c, [-3, 0, 1, 2])

for x in xx:
    print x, a*x*x + b*x + c
```

Comment: I couldn't actually figure out the last indices part. How do I implement it in python to give me the desired output i.e. the sorted y values.
example: STDIN: `$  4 0 0 -3 0 1 2`
                STDOUT: `$ 0 0 1 4 2 16 -3 36`

Comment: So it's Python again? Makes me wonder why your original code was in C++. Anyway, I've added an example.

Comment: thanks! I wrote the original code in python, wrote the c++ code aftewards. Python is easy for me to understand a bit faster, though. :)